# android ImageView doesn't show transparency

Tags: android, xml, imageview, transparency

I got a png image with as transparent color, white one which i want to use in an ImageView for an android app.
[You can check that the image has a transparency color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4diyg.png)

I added the picture to each of the folders (drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi..)
and linked the ImageView with the image.
Instead of getting a transparency color, i got a white one as shown below
[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Upl.png)
The blue screen is a RelativeLayout with background.
Here's the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/barre_puissance" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/barre_angle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_mr">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mr_projectile"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There's a yellow caution triangle at the bottom right of the image.  Where's that coming from?

Comment: It says " Missing contentDescription attribute on image "

Comment: What I mean is, what drawable in your layout has that triangle in it?

Comment: the imageView2, and i just added another picture and it worked fine, so the problem comes from the first picture, but why ?

Comment: remake it with your photoshop. if the transparency is fine with another pic, then this one's must be messed up.

Comment: (y) , the picture was the problem, thanks for the comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android XML Supports transparency with png files so problem has be with your image.
Make sure your png image file is contain transparency.

Comment: Right (y) , it was the picture, i replaced it with another one and worked fine (y) thanks for the comment

Comment: when i use `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` on my manifest i lose the transparency of all images